# Span preventing input from being focused when clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `span` `"@"` positioned absolutely within an input to guide the user to insert their twitter handle. However, the span prevents the input from being focused if I click on the `@` within the input.

Here's a jsFiddle of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/UxQet/

I tried adding the following jQuery to fix it but that didn't work:

```
$(function(){
  $('td#twitter input').click(function(){
    $(this).focus();
  });
});
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Use a `background-image` or use `pointer-events: none` or `.focus()` the `input` when the `@` is clicked.

Comment: Had no idea about `pointer-events`, thanks!

Comment: Can you add that as an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Yes, `pointer-events` is an interesting solution. Unfortunately IE dosn't support it (what a surprise) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$("td#twitter p").click(function() {
  $(this).next().focus();
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/UxQet/3/)** is the code.